# Почему разрывает соединение при выполнении скрипта?

Tags: python, telnet

Сделал скрипт на python, скрипт начинает работать, соединяется выполняет свои действия, и после того как отработала команда connect.write(b'reset\r\n ')
(перезагрузка ОНУ),проходит time sleep и после этого новое соединение не устанавливается и выбивает ошибку.Я новичёк, буду благодарен за помощь, спасибо

**Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера**

```
import telnetlib
import time
from tkinter import *
#Заливка первого файла прошивки
          ip='192.168.100.1'
          connect=telnetlib.Telnet(ip)
          connect.write(b'root\r\n')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'admin\r\n')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'su\r\n ')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'load pack by tftp svrip 192.168.100.2 remotefile 1.bin\r\n ')
          time.sleep(35)
          <b>connect.write(b'reset\r\n ')
          time.sleep(25</b>)
#Тут момент перезагрузки, и после этого кусок кода ниже не работает
          ip='192.168.100.1'
          connect=telnetlib.Telnet(ip)
          connect.write(b'root\r\n')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'admin\r\n')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'su\r\n ')
          time.sleep(2)
          connect.write(b'load pack by tftp svrip 192.168.100.2 remotefile 2.bin\r\n ')
          time.sleep(25)
          connect.write(b'reset\r\n ')
          time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего 25 секунд мало на перезагрузку и запуск службы telnet. Попробуйте установить значение чуть больше.

```
import telnetlib
import time
from tkinter import *

ip = '192.168.100.1'
#Заливка первого файла прошивки
try:
  with telnetlib.Telnet(ip) as connect:
    connect.write(b'root\r\n')
    time.sleep(2)
    connect.write(b'admin\r\n')
    time.sleep(2)
    connect.write(b'su\r\n ')
    time.sleep(2)
    connect.write(b'load pack by tftp svrip 192.168.100.2 remotefile 1.bin\r\n ')
    time.sleep(35)
    connect.write(b'reset\r\n ')
    time.sleep(25)
except Exception as reason:
  print("Reason at first block: " + repr(reason))

#Тут момент перезагрузки, и после этого кусок кода ниже не работает
for _ in range(3):
  try:
    with telnetlib.Telnet(ip) as connect:
      connect.write(b'root\r\n')
      time.sleep(2)
      connect.write(b'admin\r\n')
      time.sleep(2)
      connect.write(b'su\r\n ')
      time.sleep(2)
      connect.write(b'load pack by tftp svrip 192.168.100.2 remotefile 2.bin\r\n ')
      time.sleep(25)
      connect.write(b'reset\r\n ')
      time.sleep(1)
    break
  except Exception as reason:
    print("Reason at second block: " + repr(reason))
```

Comment: Ставил 80сек,20 секунд ону уже перезагрузилась, и я уже через консоль могу на неё зайти, а вот в питоне вот такая проблема.Может как то скрипт поправить?

Comment: Вообще сложно сказать, что у вас конкретно не работает. Вполне возможно, что нужно закрывать соединение, а не только открывать.

Comment: Кстати хороший вопрос, приложите пожалуйста полный trace back ошибки, по вашим словам сложно понять.

Так же дополню свой ответ чуть подправленным кодом, попробуйте мой вариант.

Comment: Попробовал как вы показали, ничего не изменилось
1 кусок отрабатывает, перегружается ону,становиться доступной, через консоль винды захожу и всё доступно, а через код не хочет.

Возникло исключение: TimeoutError
[WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
  File "C:\Users\OneSmiLe\Desktop\python\import telsssssssssssssssssssnetlib.py", line 26, in <module>
    with telnetlib.Telnet(ip) as connect:

Comment: Всё таки мне нужен полный traceback. Если он длинный получается, скиньте на https://pastebin.com/.
Полный traceback это https://wampi.ru/image/RN7cSgE .

Comment: вот, вроде бы оно https://pastebin.com/u6CRKZiL

Спасибо что помогаете

Comment: вот, вроде бы оно pastebin.com/u6CRKZiL Спасибо что помогаете

Comment: у меня не так много вариантов на самом деле)

Comment: Ничего подобного в моём опыте не было, я могу предложить последний вариант, я обновлю код, но если не поможет, я не знаю в чём вопрос)

Comment: Reason at second block: TimeoutError(10060, 'Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера', None, 10060, None)


Аналогично, хотя устройство уже перезагрузилось после заливки первой прошивки.
через питон выбивает ошибку, а через систему могу зайти по телнет и могу управлять устройством, то есть оно доступно по телнет.

Comment: И таких ошибок 3?все три попытки сфейлились?

Comment: Только одна, на второй кусок там где load pack by tftp svrip 192.168.100.2 remotefile 2.bin даже не переходит.Я уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Так а если только одна ошибка появляется, значит со второй попытки все работает, в частности подключение.